Cannot Implicitly convert 'array' to 'string'...sending data from controller to chart js
Need help with my code
The problem is I tried to pass array from the controller to my page that contain a bar chart. But the chart cannot be displayed because it doesn't correctly received the array I passed from the controller.
At this Line on main.php:
var data = {$data};
there is yellow line says cannot implicitly convert array from strings
ChartController.php
class ChartController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $commonKpiTotalScoreQ1 = $this->getQuartPerformanceData(1);
        $commonKpiTotalScoreQ2 = $this->getQuartPerformanceData(2);
        $commonKpiTotalScoreQ3 = $this->getQuartPerformanceData(3);
        $commonKpiTotalScoreQ4 = $this->getQuartPerformanceData(4);

        $data = [
            'Q1' => $commonKpiTotalScoreQ1,
            'Q2' => $commonKpiTotalScoreQ2,
            'Q3' => $commonKpiTotalScoreQ3,
            'Q4' => $commonKpiTotalScoreQ4,
        ];

        return $this->render('index', [

            'data' => json_encode($data),
        ]);
    }

main.php
<?php
$this->registerJs(<<<JS

        var data = {$data};
        // Process the fetched data
        var kpiScores = [data.Q1, data.Q2, data.Q3, data.Q4];

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['1st Quarter', '2nd Quarter', '3rd Quarter', '4th Quarter'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Performance Score',
                    data: kpiScores,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        max: 100
                    }
                }
            }
        });
JS
);
?>


I see that YII2 supports registerJs with inline scripts, but this seems like it would be very error prone. I would move the JS to a .js file and include it with a <script> tag. Then get the data you need with an ajax call before creating the chart.

@kikon The brackets are for string interpolation in the php heredoc.

I would expect
$this->registerJs(<<<JS
var data = $data

@mplungjan  That was my initial guess too, but @bassxzero showed that {$data} is syntax for string interpolation in a php heredoc string, so I deleted my comment. Meanwhile I verified (php sandbox) that in a heredoc string $data and {$data} produce the same result (no extra brackets).

@kikon @mplungjan while it does work, I don't recommend it. I've had lots of problems with heredocs and nowdocs in the past and I just don't use them. Especially with JS because they have tons of { in the code.
